# How can I rotate multiple photos at once using Google Photos?

Tags: google-photos

Today I've uploaded a bunch of photos to [Google Photos](https://photos.google.com) service, but I've just noticed that half of them are rotated wrong.

I found [this solution](http://www.reddit.com/r/google/comments/39zu0s/batch_rotating_google_photos/), but for lots of photos it's too slow and boring.

> 1. Click one image
> 2. Click the pencil icon to edit
> 3. Wait for the edit interface to load
> 4. Click the crop icon (lolwut?!)
> 5. Wait for the crop interface to load
> 6. Click the rotate button once or thrice, depending on the desired orientation
> 7. Click the tick
> 8. Click save
> 9. Wait for a while while stuff happens
> 10. Click the back arrow
> 11. Welcome back to the top of your photos. Now spend a few minutes searching for the next rotated photo.

It would be better to rotate the photos in Windows, but I don't want to upload them again.

Is there a way how can I rotate more than one photo at once?

Comment: another option is just letting it be. eventually it will auto suggest to rotate them if its ai feels like it.

Answer (score 34):

While you still can't rotate multiple pictures at once, at least now there is a keyboard shortcut to rotate a picture: <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd>.

So click a picture you want to rotate, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>R</kbd> (once, or 3 times, depending on the rotation you need), then either use the arrows to go to the next picture, or back to go back to the list.

Comment: Great answer, scrolling through the photos is pretty quick actually so this isn't any more painful than selecting multiple at once.

Comment: Sadly, this doesn't work with videos :(

Answer (score -1):

With the new Google Photos app you can select multiple pictures by pressing on one and then scrolling down to the others they will be checked

Comment: That's great for selecting multiple photos. That was never the issue. The question is about how to rotate several photos simultaneously.